# fatal error: value failed to bridge from Swift type to a Objective-C type

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I am trying to write some info to `Core Data` using the new `NSBatchUpdateRequest` and can't figure out why I am getting this error. Can someone explain what is going on here? It sounds like I am having trouble converting a Swift to Objective-C type value?

```
fatal error: value failed to bridge from Swift type to Objective-C type
```

Here is my block of code that the error is taking place in:

```
func updateUser(user: User) {
    var batchRequest = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "User")

    if doesUserExist(user.userId) {
        batchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userId == %@", user.userId)
    }

    batchRequest.propertiesToUpdate = [
        "userId" : user.userId,
        "username" : user.username,
        "email" : user.email,
        "fullName" : user.fullName,
        "gender" : user.gender,
        "birthdate" : user.birthdate,
        "zipCode" : user.zipCode,
        "aboutMe" : user.aboutMe,
        "iAm" : user.iAm,
        "iLike" : user.iLike,
        "favoriteWeapon" : user.favoriteWeapon,
        "dateCreated" : user.dateCreated,
        "lookingFor" : user.lookingFor,
        "minAge" : user.minAge,
        "maxAge" : user.maxAge,
        "distance" : user.distance,
        "gameOwned" : user.gameOwned,
        "gameSetting" : user.gameSetting,
        "allowedList" : user.allowedList,
        "blockedList" : user.blockedList,
        "avatarType" : user.avatarType
    ]
    batchRequest.resultType = .UpdatedObjectsCountResultType
    var error : NSError?
    var results = self.managedObjectContext!.executeRequest(batchRequest, error: &error) as NSBatchUpdateResult
    if error == nil {
        println("Updated User: \(user.username) \(results.result)")
    }
    else {
        println("Update User Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

The line of code that I am getting the error on is:

```
var results = self.managedObjectContext!.executeRequest(batchRequest, error: &error) as NSBatchUpdateResult
```

**User Object**

```
class User: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var aboutMe: String
@NSManaged var avatarType: String
@NSManaged var birthdate: NSDate
@NSManaged var cityState: String
@NSManaged var dateCreated: NSDate
@NSManaged var distance: NSNumber
@NSManaged var email: String
@NSManaged var favoriteWeapon: String
@NSManaged var fullName: String
@NSManaged var gameOwned: AnyObject
@NSManaged var gameSetting: AnyObject
@NSManaged var gender: String
@NSManaged var iAm: String
@NSManaged var iLike: String
@NSManaged var lastMatch: NSDate
@NSManaged var lookingFor: String
@NSManaged var maxAge: NSNumber
@NSManaged var minAge: NSNumber
@NSManaged var pictureUrl: String
@NSManaged var userId: String
@NSManaged var username: String
@NSManaged var zipCode: String
@NSManaged var allowedList: String
@NSManaged var blockedList: String
```

}

Comment: Can you show your User object definition?

Comment: @MikeTaverne added User object definition.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your user object has swift specific features that are not available in objective c, like enums, tuples, generics, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue in the complier being cause by your swift optimization. One solution that worked for me was

1. Click on your target in the left sidebar.
2. Click on Build Settings
3. Search for 'Optimization level'
4. Change the values as required (we had to set the Optimization Level to -Onone to fix the bug)

Source:[How to Change the Optimization Level in Xcode 6 for Swift](http://matthewpalmer.net/blog/2014/12/11/change-optimization-level-xcode-swift/)

Answer (score 0):

You should convert all your variables containing data to String data type. Maybe your 'AnyObject' or 'Date' datatypes are creating the problem.